# How to count total uppercase letters in all list elements without converting to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

My data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'game': [1, 2], 'moves': [['D4', 'd5', 'NF4'],['d5', 'c6', 'Be4']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
| game |     moves    |
|------|--------------|
| 1    |[D4, d5, NF4]  |
| 2    |[d5, c6, Be4] |
```

For each row, I want to extract the number of uppercase letters in the first n elements of the list in the column 'moves'. So far I have this solution:

```
count = []
for row in df.moves:
    count.append(sum(1 for elem in listToString(row[0:10]) if elem.isupper()))
```

This works, but I would prefer a solution which does not involve concatenating the string elements of the lists. Is there such a thing?

Output:

```
[3, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
count = df['moves'].apply(lambda x: sum(1 for i in x[:10] for y in i if y.isupper())).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[3, 1]
```

Comment: This gives me the wrong output. I added an example with my code to the question. If I try your solution, I get  [1,1] instead of [2,1]

Comment: This seems to only count the first letter of each element. This actually works for my problem, so thanks! But I tried changing i[0] so I get all upper case letters (if I ever need that in the future). So far I was unsuccessful

Comment: I get the same results; only the first letter is considered

Comment: @PretendNotToSuck Ah i got you! edited my answer with a working code now

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehensions it is possible to do:

```
count  = [[y[0].isupper() for y in x].count(True) for x in data['moves']]
```

or if all uppercase letters needs counted:

```
count  = [sum([sum(1 for elem in y if elem.isupper()) for y in x]) for x in data['moves']]
```

and a bit better:

```
count  = [sum(1 for elem in ''.join(x) if elem.isupper())  for x in data['moves']]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only checks the first character of each entry in the list, and would miss counting the `'Y'` from an entry like `'xY4'`. Good try, though...you're pretty close.

Comment: I know. This was not clarified before hand by PretendNotToSuck.

Jan -> PretendNotToSuck: Should we count all letters or just the first one in each word?

Comment: Yes, that was the intention, Sorry for not being clear about it. But having both solutions actually benefits me.